# Using Parceler library with Serialization

Tags: android, serialization, annotations, parcelable, parceler

I want to use Parceler library with Serialization. This is what I have now without using this library:

```
public class Venue {

@SerializedName("id")
String venueID;
@SerializedName("name")
String venueName;
@SerializedName("url")
String venueUrl;


public Venue() {
}}
```

I read the library's tutorial and it says that I can just use it by adding the annotation:

```
@Parcel(Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)
```

But I still confused. As I understood I don't need to use @SerializedName annotation. So do I need to use my fields with it's original name or with there serialized name? Like this:

```
    @Parcel(Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)
    public class Venue {

        //    @SerializedName("id")
        String id;
        //    @SerializedName("name")
        String name;
        //    @SerializedName("url")
        String url;

@ParcelConstructor
    public Venue(String id, String name, String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;

    }

        public Venue() {
        }

    }
```

Or this:

```
    @Parcel(Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)
    public class Venue {
        //    @SerializedName("id")
        String vnueID;
        //    @SerializedName("name")
        String venueName;
        //    @SerializedName("url")
        String venueUrl;

@ParcelConstructor
        public Venue(String vnueID, String venueName, String venueUrl) {
            this.vnueID = vnueID;
            this.venueName = venueName;
            this.venueUrl = venueUrl;

        }

        public Venue() {
        }

    }
```

Sorry if this is dumb question, but I don't yet understand parseable and serialization yet.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Parcel.Serialization.BEAN` will direct Parceler to look for and use getters and setters in accordance with the Java Bean standard.  Your case calls for the default `FIELD` strategy which will access your `Venue` fields directly.  Parceler does not use the `@SerializedName` annotation.

This should be a reasonable configuration of your `Venue` class:

```
@Parcel
public class Venue {
    String venueID;
    String venueName;
    String venueUrl;
}
```